# ElasticSearch aggregation query with List in documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following records of car sales of different brands in different cities.

Document -1

```
{
"city": "Delhi",
"cars":[{
  "name":"Toyota",
  "purchase":100,
  "sold":80
},{
  "name":"Honda",
  "purchase":200,
  "sold":150
}]
}
```

Document -2

```
{
"city": "Delhi",
"cars":[{
  "name":"Toyota",
  "purchase":50,
  "sold":40
},{
  "name":"Honda",
  "purchase":150,
  "sold":120
}]
}
```

I am trying to come up with query to aggregate car statistics for a given city but not getting the right query.

Required result:

```
{
"city": "Delhi",
"cars":[{
  "name":"Toyota",
  "purchase":150,
  "sold":120
},{
  "name":"Honda",
  "purchase":350,
  "sold":270
}]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Are "name" Keyword? Share your mappings please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to map your array as a nested field (script would be complicated and not performant). Nested field are indexed, aggregation will be pretty fast.

remove your index / or create a new one. Please note i use test as type.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cars": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "purchase": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "sold": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index your document (same way you did)

For the aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_grade": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "resellers": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cars"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "cars.name"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "avg_pur": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "cars.purchase"
                  }
                },
                "avg_sold": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "cars.sold"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
buckets": [
{
"key": "Honda",
"doc_count": 2,
"avg_pur": {
"value": 350
},
"avg_sold": {
"value": 270
}
}
,
{
"key": "Toyota",
"doc_count": 2,
"avg_pur": {
"value": 150
},
"avg_sold": {
"value": 120
}
}
]
```

if you have index the name / city field as a text (you have to ask first if this is necessary), use .keyword in the term aggregation ("cars.name.keyword").